# How to properly quote piped command for "watch"?

Tags: command-line, watch-command

I want to keep an eye on a file as it is created. So I used this command

```
ls -hal ./file |awk '{print $5}'
```

which gives the size of the file I am looking for. I use `awk` because I don't need other stuff, just the file size.

But I'm unable to use this with `watch` command, because if I try

```
watch ls -hal ./file |awk '{print $5}'
```

then watch only accepts `ls -hal ./file` and then pipes it to `awk`, giving no output.

If I try

```
watch "ls -hal ./file |awk '{print $5}'"
```

then it gets weird showing wrong command and whole output.

```
Every 2.0s: ls -hal ./file |awk '{print }'              Sun Jul 20 15:52:18 2014

-rw-rw---- 1 aditya aditya 1.7K Jul 20 15:52 ./file
```

You can see there is no `$5` in the awk command.

Further quoting creates various similar errors.

So what is the right way to quote this command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to *escape* the `$` in your `awk` expression

```
watch "ls -hal ./file |awk '{print \$5}'"
```

Alternatively, you could avoid the issue altogether by using `stat` instead of parsing the output of `ls`

```
watch stat -c '%s' ./file
```

Comment: @RegisteredUser I recommend to accept this (steeldriver's) answer instead of mine because it gives right solution for `awk` and also sort syntax by `stat`!

Answer (score 2):

Use following command :

```
watch 'ls -hal ./file|cut -d " " -f 5'
```

And if you want to **highlight difference** than,

```
watch -d 'ls -hal ./file|cut -d " " -f 5'
```

This will give work as you want!